# Trying to solve the conditional statement question getting the answer right but have a Query in my mind

Tags: python, if-statement

```
x = 2

if x < 5:
    print("X is Smaller")

elif x < 10:
    print("X is Medium")

else:
    print("X is Bigger")

print("All Done")
```

OUTPUT:

```
X is Smaller
All Done
```

My question is x = 2 is smaller than 5 as well as 10. Then Why the output is the if statement i.e "X is smaller"??? Why not elif statement i.e "X is Medium" ??

Comment: When x meets one of the conditions, the statement under that condition will be executed, and then exit if statement directly. The following elif and else statements will not be executed.

Comment: What do you think the "el" in "elif" is for?

Answer (score 0):

Because the program can only choose one branch to execute. For your problem, x = 2, then the program checks if x is smaller than 5. The condition is satisfied, so it prints "X is smaller", and then jumps out of the if-elif-else block.

Answer (score 0):

The reason for these results is that
'e l i f` means "otherwise".
So your code is

```
x=2
if x is smaller than 5?
```

yes! true!
okay, Then I don't need to ask more. I'll finish it.

If you want to see the result "X is Medium", please refer to it.

```
x=2
if x < 5:
    print("X is Smaller")
if x < 10:
    print("X is Medium")
else:
    print("X is Bigger")

print("All Done")
```